# Ipad/Iphone UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiactionsheet

Ive only posted on here a couple of times and people have been very quick and very helpful when responding so thanks.

Im trying to use the UIActionsheet element in my Ipad application. But just to confuse matters im using Cocos2d aswell.

But here is my problem.

If coding the actionsheet with out cocos2d you would use the following code.

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

However because im using cocos2d and there is no views as such the only thing i can think of to reference is the window.. But this is located in the appdelegate class.

ive tried

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.Window];
```

and i get errors

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.window];
//---------------------------^ small "w"
```

? If this doesn't work, try also

```
[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```